# Why in the Rao-Nam private key version of McEliece scheme, P matrix is multiplied after adding error vector?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, mceliece

The private key version of McEliece known as Rao-Nam scheme, the encryption is done as c = (mSG + e)P. What is the need for applying permutation matrix on the error vector?